# SQL Problem check if column exist and if it dont exist it whall just go to catch - SQLSERVER MICROSOFT

Tags: sql

I have tryed to check if the column existed with temp table Create table #temp
I know it dosent have the FRÅGA5
But i needed to do some check on information_schema so i create a table when i execute the code and remove it later.

```
  BEGIN TRY
      IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM X.information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_TEMP_Temptable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Fråga5')
         BEGIN
         
             IF((SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(Fråga5,'')) FROM tbl_TEMP_Temptable) = 0)
            BEGIN       
                ALTER TABLE tbl_TEMP_Temptable DROP COLUMN Fråga5
            END 
        END
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH     
    END CATCH
```

But i need to do a logic that check if have the Column name FRÅGA5

And i get this error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'Fråga5'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'Fråga5'.
```

and the like it talking about is

***IF((SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(Fråga5,'')) FROM tbl_TEMP_Temptable) = 0)***

But the code shall not touch this one becouse from the start the Fråga5 column dont even exist

Comment: SQLSERVER MICROSOFT

Comment: The batch as a whole is parsed before being executed, so before anything happens it finds a parsing error because the column doesn't exist. You would need to use dynamic SQL.